# Is the product of a maximal subgroup and a cyclic subgroup a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

$G$ is a finite group. I wanted to show that for a maximal subgroup $M$ of $G$, if $g\in G\setminus M$, then $M\langle g\rangle=G$. It it true? My argument is that if $M\subset M\langle g\rangle\neq G$, then it is a contradiction to the maximality of $M$ in $G$.

But if neither $M$ nor $\langle g\rangle$ is not normal in $G$, then $M\langle g\rangle$ is not necessarily a subgroup of $G$. Hence we cannot get the contradiction from that. Could you tell me how to fix my proof? Or could you give me a counterexample if it is not true? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by $M\langle g\rangle$ you mean the subgroup generated by $M$ and $g$, then yes, you are correct. But if you mean the set product then it clearly cannot work, because the cardinality of it is at most $|M|$ times $o(g)$, the order of $g$. If $o(g)=2$ and $|G:M|>2$, like almost every maximal subgroup and many group elements, then the set product cannot be all of $G$.

Comment: I suppose it's worth mentioning that, since $g\in G\setminus M$, then, in particular, $g\neq e$, so the order of $g$ is at least two.

Comment: Also worth mentioning is that the smallest counterexample is $S_3$, with $M=\langle(1,2)\rangle$ and $g=(2,3)$.

Comment: A priori, the cardinality of it is $|M|$ times **a factor of** $o(g)$ (in particular, if some non-identity power of $g$ lies in $M$). It is possible the maximality of $M$ forces equality, but it is, in that case, something that ought to be proven, not just stated.

Comment: @Arthur I was considering the case where the element has order $p$, but you are right, it is at most that. I have corrected the solution. Even if it were equal to that, it would still be far less than the order of the group in general. For example, the Thompson group, order 90745943887872000, has a maximal subgroup $S_5$, order $120$.

Comment: Excuse me. Would you mind giving me some ideas about the following question? Denote the Thompson group by $G$ and denote a maximal subgroup isomorphic to $S_5$ by $S$. $|G|=2^{15}\times 3^{10}\times 5^3\times 7^2\times 13\times19\times 31$ has divisor $7$, so there must be an element $g$ of order $7$. I know the generated subgroup $\langle S,g\rangle$ is $G$, but what seems weird to me is where the prime divisors $13,19,31$ come from. Could you give me some ideas? Thank you!

Comment: They are just long words in the generators. $G$ is generated by an element of order $2$ and one of order $3$. Since $G$ has only one class of elements of order $3$, this second generator can be chosen to lie in $S_5$. So already the 'standard' generators for $G$ have this property.